# In SQL, how to combine two sequential rows into one when no common ID?

Tags: sql-server-2016

Have values split between multiple records without a key to join them.  The order is sequential.

Current SQL table contents:

```
RowNum    Value
1         10343  
2         20784
3         34523
4         22415
5         31245
6         11345
7         24588 
8         32946
```

I want to return rows combining the two consecutive records but only those with Values starting with 2 and 3.  There is no common column value to group on.

Desired result:

```
RowNums   Values
2-3       20784, 34523
4-5       22415, 31245
7-8       24588, 32946
```

Comment: Tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lead()`:

```
select concat(rownum, '-', next_rownum) as rownums,
       concat(value, ', ', next_value) as values
from (select t.*,
             lead(rownum) over (order by rownum) as next_rownum,
             lead(value) over (order by value) as next_value
      from t
     ) t
where value like '2%' and next_value like '3%';
```

This uses Standard SQL syntax.  There might be variations depending on your database.